# How to retrieve html document size from url in golang

Tags: html, go, document

I used GoQuery to retrieve some value within an HTML document. *Now I need to get the size of HTML document (without assets)*.
In Firefox, it's as simple as Tools --> Page Info (General) tab show the Size of the HTML document.
I tried `net/html` package as well but I can't find the size of the returned HTML given a URL. Any clues?

Comment: The `Content-Length` header on the response.

Comment: response.ContentLength is return -1, which means unknown length -(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the document via:

```
res, err := http.Get(url)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
defer res.Body.Close()
```

Now you can:

```
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
l := len(body)
```

To use with GoQuery:

```
utfBody, err := iconv.NewReader(res.Body, charset, "utf-8")
if err != nil {
    // handler error
}

doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(utfBody)
if err != nil {
    // handler error
}
```

More datail about GoQuery and readers is [here](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery/wiki/Tips-and-tricks).

Comment: len() function doesn't work on res.Body, which is io.Reader. I need the HTML document size in kb.

Comment: Thanks, this is the closest we have in golang for returned HTML document size in kb:
`float32(len(body) / 1024)`  
However, this value still doesn't match with the Page Info value of Firefox -(

Comment: @ShahIsmail, `this value still doesn't match with the Page Info value of Firefox` - and why it should? That value in Firefox is size in bytes of _all response_, including HTTP headers, not only size of returned html code. If you need whole transferred bytes count, examine `res.Headers` property and add total size of each header to resulting length

Comment: The value returned by this script is ~80kb while Firefox returns ~35kb. So the firefox isn't counting the header etc. As I mentioned, I need the size of HTML document (without assets).  
-->Little correction: `float32(len(body)) / float32(1024)`
The thing is, if somebody needs to verify the correctness of my solution then how would he go about it?

Comment: @ShahIsmail, are you trying to check a static page or a dynamic page? Is it a public URL or a user session based URL? Did you verified the contents whether both the HTML are same as compared with Firefox & `http.Get(url)`.

Comment: @ShahIsmail, create minimal reproducable example at [golang playground](http://play.golang.org/) so we can test it, please

Comment: http://play.golang.org/p/zhmZ1pw-1D  
It doesn't run on playgroud and complain about "Get http://.... dial tcp: protocol not available"  
But you can run it on your local machines. Basically, it's a jsp page but the server only requires cookies enabled.

Comment: @ShahIsmail there's a chance that firefox is displaying the gzip'ed size.

Comment: @OneOfOne, confirming, Firefox _actually_ shows transferred bytes (which is less for gzipped content), not html content size.